# Transformations and their dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $X$ is a linear transformation from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2×2}$ and $\mathrm{ker}(X) = \{0\}$, then which of the following statements about $\mathrm{dim}(Y)$ is necessarily true?

- $\mathrm{dim}(Y) \leq 4$
- $\mathrm{dim}(Y) \geq 4$
- $\mathrm{dim}(Y) = 4$

If the solution is necessarily true, the solutions would be $A$,$B$,$C$ given that $\mathrm{dim}(Y)$ will be $4$ necessarily?

Comment: Use MathJax in your questions to make them more accessible: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please don't use consecutive letters of the same font (such as $X$ and $Y$) for two mathematical objects that are not of the same nature (like a vector space and a transformation), this is quite confusing imho.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The is a famous theorem connecting the dimensions of kernel, image and vector space.

Comment: rank-nullity theorem

Comment: Can you identify the three different dimensions in your task?

Comment: rank nullity theorem is: Rank{T} + Nullity{T} = Dim V

Comment: rank nullity theorem is: Rank{T} + Nullity{T} = Dim V

Rank{T} = dimension of image{T} = 2 (2 column spaces)
Nullity{T} = dimension of Kernel{T} = 0 

2+0 = 2. 

So my solution is that dimensions is that it is necessarily less than or equal to 4.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Suppose $X: Y \to \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ is a linear transformation with $\text{ker}(X) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Then since $\text{ker}(X) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$, it follows that $X$ is [...]?

The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ is $4$. Therefore, since $X$ is [...], it follows that $\dim(Y) \quad ?\quad  4$.

Comment: but it says necessarily. So it's possible that its A,B,C since C = 4, but the other two are less than OR equal to, or greater than OR equal to 4.

Comment: Is this different from asking which option is true?

Comment: @mvw so all three are true? I guess my question should be framed around the term necessarily

Comment: @seekingalpha23 My only hint to you is that you only know for sure (hence "necessarily") that *one* of those is true. If you understand the logic around my answer, it should follow easily.

Comment: @seekingalpha23 I suggest you stop asking for the bare solution and start trying to use the hints provided to work out the solution yourself.

Comment: @Clarinetist

rank nullity theorem is: Rank{T} + Nullity{T} = Dim V Rank{T} = dimension of image{T} = 2 (2 column spaces) Nullity{T} = dimension of Kernel{T} = 0 2+0 = 2. So my solution is that dimensions is that it is necessarily less than or equal to 4